# Subversion: How to find old revisions?

Tags: svn

I'm noob in Subversion, how can I find my old revisions of the project in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `svn checkout` with a revision parameter, like so:

```
svn checkout -r 6
```

Also, the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is a great resource for learning svn.

Answer (score 0):

for svn commands you can check out [svn command line tutorial](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/255/svn-command-line-tutorial-for-beginners-1/)